# Undefined variable on wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I am experiencing a `Undefined variable:  warning` on my Wordpress plugin.

How would I fix this? Below is a snippet of the query within a shortcode and is not the full function. It is on the line containing $post_thumbnail that I am experiencing the issue. Thanks.

```
function project_shortcode( $atts ) {   
extract( shortcode_atts( array(  
        'limit' => '10',  
        'orderby' => 'date',  
    ), $atts ) );  
            $output = '';
            $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => $limit, 'orderby' => $orderby));  
            // Looping through the posts and building the HTML structure.  
            if($loop){  
            $output .= '<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">';
            while ($loop->have_posts()){  
             $loop->the_post(); 
             //If has thumbnail

             $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
             $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
```

**UPDATE**

Line `$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);`

Comment: There are 2 lines with `$post_thumbnail` in them. Which one?

Comment: sorry. Updated question

Comment: maybe the $post var is missing? You should also get warnings about missing $limit and $orderby vars..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, you're using vars, which aren't defined(the warning told you..).
And it's not only the `$post` var, `$limit` and `$orderby` are also not defined.

To solve your problem, you could pass all missing vars as an argument to `project_shortcode` and set them in the function call.

```
function project_shortcode($atts, $post, $orderby, $limit) //...
```

and don't forget to pass the vars..

Comment: Hi @phipipp . I now get 'Trying to get property of non-object' for the same line